# Generalization of Hensel's lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been trying to prove the following generalization of Hensel's lemma:

Let $ f\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n] $ and $ f=0 $ be a diophantine equation.

Let's assume that for some $ d \in \mathbb{N} $ there exists a solution $ (a_1, \dots, a_n) $ of $ f=0 \pmod {p^{2d+1}} $ such that:

for all $ i =1,\dots,n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (a_1, \dots, a_n) = 0 \pmod {p^d}$, but

for some $ 1 \leq i \leq n$ $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a_1, \dots, a_n) \neq 0 \pmod{p^{d+1}} $.

Prove that then:

$ \forall_{r \in \mathbb{N}} $ there exists a solution $ (b_1, \dots, b_n) $ of $ f=0 \pmod{p^r} $ such that if $ r \geq 2d+1 $, then $ b_i = a_i \pmod{p^{d+1}}$.

The only thing I managed to prove is the Hensel lemma itself. I'm sure I'm going to need induction with respect to $ r $, but I can't seem to be able to finish the proof